# Firebase equalTo doesn't works , tries to get all data

Tags: java, android, firebase, filter, firebase-realtime-database

First of all, I know it's common question, but I am really distracted right now, can't really get what I have to do, change schema (which will take too long) or I have some mistake in my code, here is a schema of Firebase nodes, example : [image]

here is how I try to query that data :

```
firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                        .child("Statistic");

        final Query query = firebaseDatabase
                .orderByChild("Programa")
                .equalTo("0010104")
                .limitToFirst(10);


        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
               for(DataSnapshot s : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
               {
                   Statistic statistic = s.getValue(Statistic.class);
                   Log.d("Found : ",statistic.getFakulteti());
               }
            }

            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
            {
                DialogFactory.errorPrompt(activity).show();
            }
        });
```

but querying doesn't works, after waiting for like minute or half, it tries to get all the data from Firebase that of course causes outOfmemory exception.

Error Log :

```
Firebase Database encountered an OutOfMemoryError. You may need to reduce the amount of data you are syncing to the client (e.g. by using queries or syncing a deeper path). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#filtering_data
                                                                        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 27113000 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 24MB until OOM
                                                                            at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:408)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaje.toString(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajc.zzsm(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajc.zzso(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajc.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajc$zzc$2.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
```

rule i tried :

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false,
      ".indexOn" : ["Programa"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database contains a very large number of `Statistic` entries, you should add an index for `Programa`.  Indexing is [described here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data).  The presence of an index allows much of the query filtering to occur on the server side and reduces the amount of data transferred to the client.

Your `logcat` output probably contains a warning like this:

```
W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Consider adding '".indexOn": "Programa"' at Statistic to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance
```

The rule for the index must include the path to your data.  If `Statistic` is the root of the path, the rule would be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false,
    "Statistic":{
      ".indexOn":"Programa"
    }
  }
}
```

When the rule is correctly specified, you will not see the warning in `logcat` about *Using an unspecified index*.  If you continue to see the warning, the rule is not correct.

Comment: I will try it in few minutes and will reply asap , thank you in advance

Comment: i tried indexing , probably it's for rest api only , error i am getting right now ( i deleted indexing, because it was not reading data at all , not even sending request after that)

Comment: Indexing works for all APIs, including Android.  Post the rules you tried.

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false,
      ".indexOn" : ["Programa"]
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

In your question I can see multiple things... **The first one** is, your programa key is an String, then if no exists a string value equal to `"0010104"`, don't find anything and if we supose that exists then you get the ten first ones. Is possible this case? If you want to get string key to contains in a part `"0010104"`  then you need yo use `startAt()` or `endAt()` instead of `equalsTo()`.

**The second one** is, how many nodes would contains Statistic node? If your answer is hundred or less (for example), then we can't do anything but if your answer is **infinite** then is the typical case of firebase, **normalize the firebase database**, how to do this? Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40887512/3996257) that I answered yesterday about this theme.

Let me know if I have helped you and good programming!

Comment: there is 28k objects of Statistic, i tried also the start and endAt and doesn't works, also indexing which than i find out only works on rest api , should i move on rest api?  normalize firebase database , yeap as i mentioned it will take too long too too long :D to refactor that data right? unless there is anyway for quick refactoring which i don't know